# Cannot change Top css value in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code in a ready function. The if works fine, but keeps top: 0 forever. The else statement works for the cholder element, but not the openercheck. Please advise.

```
    if($('.openercheck').prop('checked', false)){
    $('.openercheck').css('top', '0px');
  }
  else{

    $('.cholder').css('height', $('.slide'+classnumber).height()+12+'px');
    $('.openercheck').css('top', $('.cholder').height()+'px');
  }
```

Comment: Wild guess - try `setTimeout(function(){ $('.openercheck').css('top', $('.cholder').height()+'px'); },0)` and let me know if that works. Also, try putting the code in a `$(window).load` instead of a `$(document).ready`

Comment: Is this run once, on page-load, or inside of a `change` event-handler?

Answer (score 1):

`$('.openercheck').prop('checked', false))` always true, because return the jQuery Object.
Try this:

```
if($('.openercheck').prop('checked')){
    $('.openercheck').css('top', '0px');
} else{
    $('.cholder').css('height', $('.slide'+classnumber).height()+12+'px');
    $('.openercheck').css('top', $('.cholder').height()+'px');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all,

```
$('.openercheck').prop('checked', false)
```

is going to set your checked property to false.

If you want to do a condition, just do something like that:

```
if($('.openercheck').prop('checked') == 'false')
```

for the last line you can do: (but I'm not so sure atm, I prefer using .attr, or .prop and not directly .css

```
$('.openercheck').css('top', $('.cholder').css('height') +'px');
```

Hope this can help.